# Error with API Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to add the library "Facebook" to Android Studio but without success ...

I saw the Official Guide facebook, and also saw some videos on youtube, but the problem comes after me to import the module and pulls me the below error:

**Error:(15, 0) Could not find property 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION' on project ':facebook'.**

Googling a bit solve it manually by typing the minimum version of Sdk and everything else so that I remain so :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
```

Now the error is pulling me the below :

**Error:(111, 0) Cannot call getBootClasspath() before setTargetInfo() is called.**

And until there comes ...

What is the matter? That 's what I'm doing wrong?

I appreciate any help before hand .

Greetings and thanks !

Comment: Can you tell me which gradle plugin version are you using? You can find it under build.gradle in your external folder of your project --> dependencies --> classpath

P.s. i figured now that you can't comment with 1 reputation, edit your question adding this information please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that your problem here is that you are using 1.1.0 gradle plugin version. Something like that:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
}
```

As you can read here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=152811, this is a bug in 1.1.0 gradle version.
You can fix it changing the version value to 1.1.1 or higher:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.1'
}
```

P.s. you can find the project dependencies classpath under your external project directory in `build.gradle` file.

Comment: That was the problem ! Many Thanks!